# Finding when shapes overlap and lines intersect but exclude points/edges

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, geometry

I've been looking for a c# algorithm to help determine if shapes and lines intersect but want to exclude boundary overlaps. Here's an example:

[image]

My true problem is finding if polygons intersect but exclude boundary overlaps. I broke down the problem to look at the individual lines of that polygon and check each line segment from the shape1 against each line segment from shape2.

A: Is this an efficient/correct way to do the checking?

B: How do I ignore when they are on the boundary as illustrated above?

Here's some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119451/how-to-tell-if-a-line-intersects-a-polygon-in-c) - I've been testing for line segments but it fails on fig 2, when the end point of the 2nd line segment finishes on the end point of the 1st segment.

```
private bool DoesLineIntersect(Vector2 start1, Vector2 end1, Vector2 start2, Vector2 end2)
{
    float denom = ((end1.x - start1.x) * (end2.y - start2.y)) - ((end1.y - start1.y) * (end2.x - start2.x));

    //  AB & CD are parallel 
    if (denom == 0)
        return false;

    float numer = ((start1.y - start2.y) * (end2.x - start2.x)) - ((start1.x - start2.x) * (end2.y - start2.y));

    float r = numer / denom;

    float numer2 = ((start1.y - start2.y) * (end1.x - start1.x)) - ((start1.x - start2.x) * (end1.y - start1.y));

    float s = numer2 / denom;

    if ((r < 0 || r > 1) || (s < 0 || s > 1))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just throwing a random idea out here: What if you change the line `if ((r < 0 || r > 1) || (s < 0 || s > 1))` to `if ((r =< 0 || r >= 1) || (s =< 0 || s >= 1))`?

Comment: Yeah it works :) passes tests. Note =< is <= ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your final check to also check for equality. So change the line

```
if ((r < 0 || r > 1) || (s < 0 || s > 1))
```

to

```
if ((r <= 0 || r >= 1) || (s <= 0 || s >= 1))
```